# Can we change Razorpay Status "Authorize" to "Capture" from flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

Is it possible to change Razorpay Status from Flutter?

I am using razorpay for my app and after getting success status the the status of Razorpay payment is "Authorized". I need to change this status to "Captured".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `capture` API  `/payments/:id/capture` for converting the status. [source](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/#capture-a-payment)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

final paymentId = 'your_payment_id';

final apiKey = 'your_razorpay_api_key';

final url = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/$paymentId/capture';

final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$apiKey:')),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // Payment captured successfully
} else {
  // Error occurred while capturing payment
}
```

Comment: The method 'capture' isn't defined for the type 'Razorpay'. this message is showing and it is giving error sir.

Comment: @SugamDas Updated the code, please check now

Comment: sir still it is not working sir

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: okay I debug and got the problem... it is giving 401 sir-"Unauthorized"

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: sir in api key I am using our api key of razorpay but it is giving 401. did you know any solution for that?

Comment: May be key is not valid, try creating a new key

Comment: final paymentId = response.paymentId.toString();
    String apiKey = 'rzp_test_RRCUjOuEtGsKWN';
    String secretKey = '7NEI87URORpnFLKlneluE9yk';
    final url = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/$paymentId/capture';
    final responseApi = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$apiKey:$secretKey')),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    );

    if (responseApi.statusCode == 200) {
      // Payment captured successfully
    } else {
     
    }

Comment: sir I have done above code but now I am getting 400 from response. can you solve that why?